# What type of list should be used for a timeline?

Tags: html-lists, wai-aria

An online exercise I am doing gave as a solution for building a timeline an ordered list.
I had constructed the timeline using a description list, since I thought it would look weird to have a number or letter preceding a year.

I think a description list looks better, but I'm wondering about WAI-ARIA: does it make sense for a timeline to be constructed as an ordered list so the progression is semantically logical as well as in appearance?

And, if so, is it possible to hide the ordinal indicator (i.e., letter, number) of the `<ol>`?

Comment: If you say you’re "wondering about WAI-ARIA", do you really refer to the [WAI-ARIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAI-ARIA) spec, or do you mean accessibility in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you've suggested, it's all about semantics. Without referring to a spec, it makes sense to use HTML elements that "suggest" to someone/something (developers/machines) reading the code directly that there's further meaning, in this case the data following a logical order.

Other examples would be semantic elements introduced in HTML5 like `<header>`, `<article>`, `<section>`, `<aside>`, `<time>` or even older elements like `<address>`.

Comparing your two options:

- An ordered list `<ol>` implies that the data is ordered, which suits a list of dates/events in a timeline.
- A data list `<dl>` uses term elements `<dt>` for holding the term/name and description elements `<dd>` for describing that term. Depending on the type of timeline, it could be argued that a year is the term, but are you describing it as a term? Most likely it's not being described but just used as a point in time for other data (think: x-axis).

Furthermore, using an ordered list would mean:

- Other developers (even in the CSS/JS) would know to respect the order, whether that be in the generation of those elements or in the styling, and get some insight into the data.
- If you have an end user with a disability using a screen-reader, the reader can respect that order (think: cooking instructions).

So an ordered list is probably most appropriate, though don't lose sleep over your choice either, we're almost splitting hairs in this case.

If you need to hide the ordinal indicator you can do that quite easily with CSS:

```
ol { 
    list-style: none; // removes ordinal indicator 
    padding-left: 0; // removes the left-over space, if needed
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. It's a tough call between `ol` and `dl`, but it certainly isn't one to lose sleep over, like you've said.

Comment: No worries. I added some cases worth considering from perspective of other devs or those with accessibility issues and a screenreader.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. This explains the idea perfectly, especially in how a timeline isn't describing a year but rather using the number as the ordinal (which is not actually what the HTML would be doing, but I see clearly how the CSS can hide the actual ordering scheme). Thank you again!

Comment: Do you know how a screen reader processes the tags? I could imagine that ``<ol>`` is prefixed with its number like ``First: 2016 foo, Second: 2017 bar, Third: 2018 baz`` while ``<ul>`` may just be read as bullet points with a short pause in between and definition lists possibly as ``2018 is baz`` or similar. Is there some reference / test site for this? If it is only for years (days, or any other items with a single number), maybe an ``<ol>`` with the year as value in ``<li value="2018">`` could be nice.

Comment: Good point @allo. I do not know actually, but it wouldn't be too hard to find out I suppose with a basic HTML page and some kind of reader. I suppose learning how they operate by using them should really be part of any developer education...

Comment: Thank @MichaelSkaggs, and welcome to StackOverflow. You'll certainly find a home here for any questions you have while learning. If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, @benmccallum! It's been duly marked.

Comment: @allo would it matter, then, that if the ordered list began with 2018, a screen reader would think it was number 2,018 in a series (even if it was the first item encountered on the list)?

Comment: I think we should not speculate too much. I bet every screen reader is different and some may be more smart than others. We should either test it our self or open a question about screen readers on stackoverflow ;).

Comment: I use a screen reader.  If your style turns off the ordinal number or bullet points, then those decorative elements won't be announced.  The list will just say it's a list with X number of items.  No numbering is implied other than the order they're in the DOM

Comment: Awesome @slugolicious, thanks for the info! Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @slugolicious, are you saying an <ol> with hidden ordinal number, the reader just treats it as a list and doesn't mentioned it has a specific order? I guess if it reads as DOM order it doesn't matter either way.

Comment: @benmccallum, that's exactly right.  If there are no list decorations, the screen reader will just read the text associated with the `<li>` and that's all.